# Razor C# Server.Execute returning Error executing child request for

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I am trying to execute an ASP.Net razor web page within another page with the intention of using the string returned in an email body (so I can have dynamic data within the email)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        @{ string response = "";
            var sw = new StringWriter();
            Server.Execute("~/WebPage.cshtml", sw, false);
            response = sw.ToString();
        }

        <p>@response</p>

    </body>
</html>
```

The page returns

```
Error executing child request for /WebPage.cshtml.
```

with a stack trace of

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): Error executing child request for /WebPage.cshtml.]
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride) +2684
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(String path, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm) +1273
   ASP._Page_RazorSamplePage_cshtml.Execute() in \\***\*******\********\RazorSamplePage.cshtml:17
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +280
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +360
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +110
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContextBase httpContext) +218
```

WebPage.cshtml can be processed just fine within a browser so I have no idea as to what the issue is. Is it a trust setting on the server?

The child page (WebPage.cshtml ) code is below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>@DateTime.Now</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please include the server side code, attributes and all

Comment: should you be calling a controller action instead of the view?

Comment: @martijn, I have now edited to included all server side code.

Comment: @SteveHarris, I am not using MVC so there is no controller / view / model separation.